# Cucumber to test Email Parsing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, sendgrid

this is my first stackoverflow question.

I am building an app that gets posted an email from SendGrid, which I then want to parse in a delayed job.

My concern is how do I QA this. I have been reading about Cucumber and that sounds like a good solution but I can't figure out the end to end test flow.

Here's where I am so far.

1. I want to have a large list of TXT files that include various types of email body's
2. I then iterate through each txt file, and make sure that when passed to a method in my lib directory /mailingjob.rb, that what is returned matches something defined in cucumber.

So what I have so far is something like:

```
expected = File.open('???/mail1.txt', 'r') do |f|
  f.read
end
```

That's where I'm starting. So if you can, please help me understand the following:

1. Where should all these TXT files be located in the rails project directory?
2. One e2e example showing how to grab a local text file, pass it to a method in the /lib directory, and then make sure what is returned equals what is set for that file path.

Thank you thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Hi Zabba thank you for the edit. Did you change something? (I'm new)

Comment: Yes, I removed "(newbie)" from the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would probably store these files somewhere in your `test` or `spec` directory (depending on what testing framework you use; you mentioned Cucumber, which I'm not super familiar with, but I think it uses a directory called `features`). Really, you could put them anywhere you want, but some subdirectory of your test directory makes sense.
2. If you're not familiar with testing with Cucumber, I recommend Railscast [episode 155](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) and [episode 159](http://railscasts.com/episodes/159-more-on-cucumber) to get you started. To answer your *direct* question, you would read the email from the text file as such

   ```
   email_text = File.read("#{Rails.root}/test/path/to/email.txt")
   ```

   `Rails.root` always refers to the root directory for your project, and makes it easy to build paths to other files or folders.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, but that talks about #1, any thoughts on #2, How to then use these TXT files, pass to a method, and see if the return equals some set response per that text file?

Comment: Well, how you go about that depends on the testing framework you're using. At it's simplest you could do something like `parsed_email = MyEmailParser.parse(email_text)` and then check to see if `parsed_email` is what you think it should be. That part is up to you! Learning a testing framework like RSpec or Cucumber will put you on the right track. That's why I recommended the screencasts.

Comment: Thanks, I've watched those and read the RSPEC book from start to finish but they don't cover the use case above. Pretty typical, and something you can usually overcome with experience on a technology, I just don't have that experience yet with cucumber. which is why I was hoping for some help :)